# Emulator to test APK

Tags: android, testing, apk

Is there any emulator, which tests the APK, for all kind of android devices. There is one called [YouWave](https://youwave.com/), but it is not good.

What I want is, one emulator, when the APK file is loaded, performs automatic testing like UI interface, performance, etc, and provide a report for the same. Saying that for this combination your APK does not works correctly.

Comment: you can use Bluestack. http://www.bluestacks.com/

Answer (score 22, accepted):

> This might not be the answer to your question but just from my
> experience I would like to share that the best practice would be to
> get as much real devices as you can. Obviously devices costs but
> that's how you can be sure about it.

As also suggested above you can give a try to [bluestacks](http://www.bluestacks.com/) as would get the `wifi` and system tools easily connected to you i.e. better in performance then the native emulator provided by Android.

With that the best thing would be to get your app tested on some devices of different `Classes`.

By classes above I mean ,

- Different resolutions
- Screen sizes
- Android versions

Or, these days some testing organizations are also there who have got a number of devices and they do the testing for you on real devices hence you won't need to pay for a device , its just a suggestion or you can suggest to someone.

**--Edit--**
I recently have gone through Genymotion and I have found it better then any other emulators,

http://www.genymotion.com/

**--Update - Nov 2020--**

Bluestacks has improved a lot lately and is free to use for most of the features. I have tried testing multiple instances of the app and it worked like charm by emulating two phones, sharing data via links etc.

Comment: Bluestack have crashed windows 10 system multiple time. Also heard about bloatware problem in it

Answer (score 12):

Use [manymo.com](http://manymo.com). This is an Online emulator for android.

Answer (score 5):

Take a look at:

- http://www.neotys.com/product/mobile-load-testing.html
- http://www.perfectomobile.com/portal/cms/services/android
- http://www.t-plan.com/robot/

Meanwhile, if you don't find a solution, [here](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/common-android-virtual-device-configurations/) you have some common android virtual device configurations, so you can easily configure yourself different devices in the AVD:

- HTC Evo 4G
- Google/HTC Nexus One
- Motorola Droid
- T-Mobile/HTC G1
- Archos 5 Internet Tablet

Answer (score 3):

**If you want the application to work perfectly in all kind of android devices, then the answer is "NO".**

As Prateek suggested in his answer, you will have to get your app tested on some real devices of different Classes.

If you don't have the resources to do the testing yourself, go for getting help from someone who have got a number of devices and tests the Apk file on real devices.

Answer (score 1):

to test online, use [appetize](https://appetize.io/) and upload your apk. very easy. they will send a link to test.

Answer (score 0):

The android SDK comes with a UI tester that allows for automated UI tests, full details can be found on the android developer site:

http://developer.android.com/tools/testing/testing_ui.html

You can test buttons, rotating the screen and get detailed information, it sounds as if it's perfectly capable of meeting your requirements

Answer (score 0):

[Andyroid](http://www.andyroid.net/) will do exactly what you need:

- Provides seamless sync between desktop and mobile devices.
- Connects Win/Mac with Android apps for launching, push notifications and storage.
- Enables app download from any desktop browser direct to Andy OS.
- Ensures most up to date Android OS at all times.
- Brings your favorite communication and entertainment mobile apps to the desktop.