# Android App testing on Different devices

Tags: android, performance, performance-testing

I want to test my android app on as many devices as possible before releasing it to PlayStore. Is there some way to do that as I've only few devices available. And I want to test only on real devices.

Comment: If you plan on doing serious Android work, you should plan to invest a small amount of money into having some devices around.  Besides this, you could use the emulator, which I personally don't like.

Comment: [Read here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17082924/5134647)

Comment: I tested my app on 7 different devices and I uploaded on PlayStore, and then it crashed on one particular device because one particular camera mode was not available on that device.

Comment: Use https://www.genymotion.com/ for testing its great

Comment: https://www.genymotion.com/ is good in many aspects. But having real device is much appreciated. Atleast few OS versions.

Comment: Actually my app uses internet connection, GPS, camera and many more features which only can be tested on real devices.

Answer (score 0):

You can checkout [Nativetap](http://Nativetap.io) which allows you to remotely test your application on many devices remotely as if it was in your hand, with multitouch gesture support, performance profiling, screenshots, session recording, etc. Nativetap allows you to test on some of the latest devices like S8/S8+, LG G6, etc. in their physical UI.

DISCLOSURE: I work with Nativetap.